# Past Papers Of multivariable calculus OF MIT,Princeton or harvard

Tags: reference-request

Does anybody know from where to get the past 10 years of papers finals?

Comment: at the teacher office

Comment: Wouldn't the math student unions (or whatever clubs they have) stockpile copies of old exams? At least that's the way it's done in these parts. Why do you think having these would help you?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen im 10000 miles away from them haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://examswithsolutions.com/Subjects/math_exams.html ..check this out and best of luck for your exams

Comment: tons of thnx !!!!!